# Matlab : reshaping matrix from a vector

Tags: matlab

I've been making a multi-channel steaming DAQ system in Labview.

And, I bring the saved binary file into Matlab for post-processing.

I need to sort the file data, according to channels.

An example is below.

with 3 multiple channel acquisition and 5Hz sampling rate

First channel voltage : 1V(constant)

Second channel voltage : 2V(constant)

Third channel voltage : 3V(constant)

if I acquire signals for 4 seconds with this condition, the saved data will be like below, because the system saves the signal in buffer, once in a second, on a single file.

```
ch1=[1 1 1 1 1];
ch2=[2 2 2 2 2];
ch3=[3 3 3 3 3];

B=[ch1 ch2 ch3 ch1 ch2 ch3 ch1 ch2 ch3 ch1 ch2 ch3];
```

I want to rearrange the data like below.

```
desiredB=[ch1 ch1 ch1 ch1; ch2 ch2 ch2 ch2; ch3 ch3 ch3 ch3];
```

In order to rearrange B I made a code like below with two for loop.

```
fs=5; %sampling frequency
nCh=3; %number of channels
nB=length(B);



C=zeros(nB/fs,fs);

for i=1:nB/fs;

     temp=B((i-1)*fs+1:fs*i);
     C(i,1:fs)=temp;

end

sizeC=size(C);

T=sizeC(1)/nCh;

D=zeros(nCh,fs*T);

for j=1:T

    temp2=C(3*(j-1)+1:3*j,:);
    D(:,(j-1)*fs+1:j*fs)=temp2;

end

t_axis=0:1/fs:T-1/fs;


plot(t_axis,D','linewidth',2),grid on
axis([0 3.8 0 5])
xlabel('time(sec)')
ylabel('voltage(V)')
legend('first channel','second channel','third channel')
```

It worked, but when I read a big size data, it's slow.

Are there any nice ways to reshape this kind of data?

Comment: Have you forgotten by any chance commas here: `B=[ch1 ch2 ch3 ;ch1 ch2 ch3; ch1 ch2 ch3 ;ch1 ch2 ch3];`?

Comment: @brodroll That would be too easy. ;)

Comment: @brodroll It's just an example. Generally, number of channel is over 30 and sampling rate is over 10kHz. With your way, It would be real hard working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
fs=5; %sampling frequency
nCh=3; %number of channels
ch1=[11 12 13 14 15];
ch2=[21 22 23 24 25];
ch3=[31 32 33 34 35];
B=[ch1 ch2 ch3 ch1 ch2 ch3 ch1 ch2 ch3 ch1 ch2 ch3];
C = reshape(B, fs, nCh, []);
D = permute(C, [1, 3, 2]);
E = reshape(D, [], nCh).'

E =

   11   12   13   14   15   11   12   13   14   15   11   12   13   14   15   11   12   13   14   15
   21   22   23   24   25   21   22   23   24   25   21   22   23   24   25   21   22   23   24   25
   31   32   33   34   35   31   32   33   34   35   31   32   33   34   35   31   32   33   34   35
```